# Projection in linear algebra

Tags: linear-transformations

Let $V$ be a vector space over $F$ and let $α, β$ be projections on $V$ satisfying the condition
that $Im(α)$ and $Im(β)$ are disjoint. Is it necessarily true that $αβ$ = $βα$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Images cannot be disjoint: do you mean $\text{Im}(\alpha)\cap\text{Im}(\beta)=\{0\}$?

Answer (score 1):

Since the condition $\operatorname{Im}(\alpha)\cap\operatorname{Im}(\beta)=\emptyset$ never holds (because $0\in\operatorname{Im}(\alpha)\cap\operatorname{Im}(\beta)$), the statement is vacuously true.

Answer (score 0):

N0.

I think you mean $\text{Im}(\alpha)\cap\text{Im}(\beta)=\{0\}.$

Consider $ \alpha=\left(\begin{matrix}1 & 0\\1 & 0\end{matrix}\right)$ and $\beta=\left(\begin{matrix}1 & 0\\-1 & 0\end{matrix}\right).$